# Applying a decorator to every method in a class?

Tags: python, decorator

I have decorator `@login_testuser` applied to method `test_1()`:

```
class TestCase(object):
    @login_testuser
    def test_1(self):
        print "test_1()"
```

Is there a way I can apply `@login_testuser` on *every* method of the class prefixed with `"test_"`?

In other words, the decorator would apply to `test_1()`, `test_2()`  methods below, but not on `setUp()`.

```
class TestCase(object):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_1(self):
        print "test_1()"

    def test_2(self):
        print "test_2()"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Python 2.6, a [class decorator](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3129-class-decorators) is definitely the way to go.  e.g., here's a pretty general one for these kind of tasks:

```
import inspect

def decallmethods(decorator, prefix='test_'):
    def dectheclass(cls):
        for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.isfunction):
            if name.startswith(prefix):
                setattr(cls, name, decorator(m))
        return cls
    return dectheclass


@decallmethods(login_testuser)
class TestCase(object):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_1(self):
        print("test_1()")

    def test_2(self):
        print("test_2()")
```

will get you what you desire.  In Python 2.5 or worse, the `@decallmethods` syntax doesn't work for class decoration, but with otherwise exactly the same code you can replace it with the following statement right *after* the end of the `class TestCase` statement:

```
TestCase = decallmethods(login_testuser)(TestCase)
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure. Iterate all attributes of the class. Check each one for being a method and if the name starts with "test_". Then replace it with the function returned from your decorator

Something like:

```
from inspect import ismethod, getmembers
for name, obj in getmembers(TestCase, ismethod):
   if name.startswith("test_"):
       setattr(TestCase, name, login_testuser(obj))
```

Comment: I would even put that in a class-decorator.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you wouldn't be better off by putting login_testuser's code into setUp instead?  That's what setUp is for: it's run before every test method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I wish to apply the decorator only to methods with a particular prefix, and setUp will apply to all methods.

Comment: Perhaps segregate those methods into their own class then?  Magic inspection and augmentation of methods sounds like a mysterious maintenance headache.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can loop over the class's `dir`/`__dict__` or have a metaclass that does so, identifying if the attributes start with "test". However, this will create less straightforward, explicit code than writing the decorator explicitly.