# Decorator and error function() argument 1 must be code, not str

Tags: python, decorator

I have next code

```
def timer_dec(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t = time.time()
        args[0].debug('<{}> start'.format(f.__name__))
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        args[0].debug('<{}> finish'.format(f.__name__))
        args[0].debug("Working time for function <%s>: %f" % (f.__name__, time.time() - t))
        return  res

    return wrapper
```

This is works fine:

```
@timer_dec
class A(object):
  pass
```

But this is not working:

```
@timer_dec
class A(object):
  pass

class B(A):
  pass
```

> TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases function() argument
>   1 must be code, not str
>
> Python version is 2.7

Comment: Could you give an example of a decorator for class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using a function decorator as a class decorator.

```
@timer_dec
class A(object):
  pass
```

is equivalent to

```
class A(object):
  pass
A = timer_dec(A)
```

Because `timer_dec` returns a function, `A` is now a function.

---

You can create a class decorator that applies a function decorator to all methods of the class. See here for an example: [Alex Martelli's answer to Applying python decorators to methods in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2238076/222914)

Comment: This is true for Python 3 too, which gives the same useless error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your decorator is returning a function. Thus, after the decorator call, the name "A" is bound to a function, not a class.
Then, you try to inherit B from the function A, which is illegal.