# Simplest way to subclass Set in a way that modifies Set methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, containers

I want to subclass set in Python so that it behaves as much as a regular set as possible, with a small modification, as shown below.

```
from typing import Iterable, Any
from collections.abc import MutableSet


class MSet(MutableSet):
    """ Set with a filename attribute """
    def __init__(self, fname: str, iterable: Iterable = None):
        self._fname = fname
        if iterable is None:
            self.elements = set()
        else:
            self.elements = set(iterable)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"NAME:{self._fname}; VALUE:{self.elements}"

    def __contains__(self, value: Any) -> bool:
        return value in self.elements

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterable:
        return iter(self.elements)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.elements)

    def add(self, value: Any) -> None:
        self.elements.add(value)

    def discard(self, value: Any) -> None:
        self.elements.discard(value)

    @property
    def filename(self) -> str:
        return self._fname
```

This is fine, but I want to be able to make it so that the double-under methods

```
__le__, __lt__, __eq__, __ne__, __gt__, __ge__, __and__, __or__, __sub__, __xor__, 
isdisjoint, __ior__, __iand__, __ixor__, and __isub__
```

only work when two MSet instances share the same "self._fname". In other words, if I want to make a comparison between mset_a, and mset_b, where their file names are "a.txt" and "b.txt", I want the following:

```
mset_a = MSet("a.txt", [1, 2, 3])
mset_b = MSet("b.txt", [2, 3, 4])

mset_a & mset_b  # raise exception
```

How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: At a minimum, you would only need to implement the *required* **Abstract Methods** shown in that column of the table of [Collections Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) for the `MutableSet` class — which are merely `__contains__`, `__iter__`, `__len__`, `add`, and `discard` — and make each check the `_filename` attribute of their operands. Performance would be much better if you also implemented some or all the optional **Mixin Methods** shown in that column of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `__and__` method:

```
def __and__(self, other):
    if self.filename != other.filename:
        raise Exception()
    return self.elements & other.elements
```

Comment: Do I override this behavior in all of the other double-underscore methods? I would be inserting the same behavior multiple on methods that take the same input types. Is there a better way?

Comment: @user3166083 You might want to use a decorator

Comment: I could use a decorator. Ideally I would wrap all of the methods to include this behavior in a for loop, rather than do it all by hand. Is this approach possible?

Comment: @user3166083 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237624/applying-a-decorator-to-every-method-in-a-class